# How to send MMS by intent in android 5.0 or Higher?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getActivity());
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        sharingIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        sharingIntent.setData(Uri.parse("address" + "1234567890"));
        sharingIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ImageUri);
        sharingIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Send"));
```

I tried this code but it's not working in 5.0 and higher version of android.

Comment: show how you get the image uri

Comment: Do you have your app permissions ? can you share it plz?

Comment: these permission are using 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />